# Compare colour values OpenGL & C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb

I am working on a tetris type game using OpenGL and C++ where if you match 3 tiles in a row of the same color, they disappear. Right now I'm working on the function which recognizes if there are 3 of the same color in a row. I am creating an `Array` which gets the colors of each grid, and determines if there are 3 matching colors.

I am having problems with comparing the colors in each array. For some reason, `(rowcolours[j]) == rowcolours[j+1])` always turns up false when the values are the same.

```
//Global variable
vec4 boardcolours[1200];

//---------------------------------------

void check3match()
{
    vec4 rowcolours[10]; // initializes array to be filled

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rowcolours[i] = boardcolours[(6*i)+1]; // fill array with color values
        //visual aid to determine if values are equal. This shows up.
        cout << "Row" <<  i+1 <<" : " << rowcolours[i] << " - " << boardcolours[(6*i)+1] << endl;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        if ((rowcolours[j]) == rowcolours[j+1]) && (rowcolours[j+1] == rowcolours[j+2]))
        {
            // another visual aid, I'm not seeing this :(
            cout << "Row" << j+1 << " = " << j+2<< " = " << j+3 << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Sample output:
    Row 1: ( 0, 1, 0, 1)
    Row 2: ( 0, 1, 0, 1)
    Row 3: ( 0, 1, 0, 1)
    Row 4: ( 1, 1, 0, 1)
    Row 5:  ...

I'm very confused as to why this is not working. Am I using the wrong comparison operator? I am new to both C++ and OpenGL, and do not know how else to compare the two arrays. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your color values are *arrays* (look how vec4 is defined).  If a and b are arrays, then `a == b` doesn't compare array elements. It compares array addresses. If the two arrays are different, their addresses will be different.

Comment: N.M is right. In the vec4 class you have to overload the == operator and implement the comparison yourself.

Comment: Or use `std::equal`. But perhaps we're all mistaken and the OP happens to use some unrelated, different `vec4` type.

Comment: Why are you using the RGBA values of your colors, instead of some common name for them (like an enumeration with `red`, `green`, `blue`, etc)?

Comment: In the sample output you are showing, there are never 3 tiles of the same color in a row. So at least in this example, you wouldn't expect to get any matches for the second condition.

Comment: try comparing all the items inside `vec4 x,y` like `if ((x.r==y.r)&&(x.g==y.g)&&(x.b==y.b)&&(x.a==y.a)) ...` also you do not account for possibility that the values are truncated to binary format and can be slightly different ... if the values are float you should check with some delta ... `if ((fabs(x.r-y.r)<delta)&& ...` where delta is some small enough number like `1e-6`. If you want to have simpler comparisons and arithmetics you can use 32bit integer color format RGBA where each channel is 8 bit wide. `DWORD col=0x00FFFFFF; glcolor4ubv((BYTE*)(&col));` is white for example.

Comment: also if you are comparing different pixel format colors there is possibility that r,g,b values are reversed between OpenGL and other API...